# Excel reader cells how to know when stop reading rows

Tags: java, excel

I have a java class that reads data from a excel. I have 2 columns. First column has always data, but the second one can have empty cells.
If there is a empty cell in on second column the program stops reading. I want to know how to change and made the loop stops when there is no more values in first column.

```
<loop startRow=\"4\" endRow=\"4\" items=\"" +
mapping.append(     "<loopbreakcondition>");
        mapping.append(         "<rowcheck offset=\"1\">");
        mapping.append(             "<cellcheck offset=\"0\"/>");
        mapping.append(         "</rowcheck>");
        mapping.append(     "</loopbreakcondition>");
```

Comment: I don't see any Java here.  Why is your question tagged Java?

Comment: @JimGarrison yes, is java code, every line has mapping.append(

Answer (score 0):

Already solve, with this loopbreakcondition

```
mapping.append(         "<rowcheck offset=\"0\">");
        mapping.append(             "<cellcheck offset=\"0\"/>");
        mapping.append(         "</rowcheck>");
        mapping.append(     "</loopbreakcondition>");
```

This code line is for stop readeing when the next row, the cell of the offset is null, so with that line if the next row, the first cell is null it will stop reading

```
cellcheck offset=\"0\"/>");
```